# Showing $((A→B)→A)→A$ and $A,B ⊢ ¬(A→¬B)$ using Deduction Theorm, etc.

Tags: logic

Using the *Deduction Theorem* and the principles of *Ex Falso*, *Reductio ad Absurdum*, and *Indirect Proof*, I am to show that:

> (a) $$((A→B)→A)→A$$

and

> (b)   $$A,B ⊢ ¬(A→¬B)$$

I know how to forumlate the principles mentioned and I also intuitively see that (a) and (b) are valid. My problem, however, is that I actually can't figure out how to use the principle mention to show this ...

I would love it if someone could offers some assistance in showing how we apply the principle in order to show (a) and (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) [Peirce's law] see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123969/prove-lnot-lnot-p-rightarrow-p-rightarrow-p-rightarrow-q-rightarr) : it is enough to omit steps 1) and 13).

For (b) :

> $A,B \vdash ¬(A → ¬B)$

we have the following proof :

1) $A$ --- premise

2) $B$ --- premise

3) $A → ¬B$ --- assumed [a]

4) $¬B$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-elimination (*modus ponens*)

5) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\lnot$-elimination

> 6) $\lnot (A → ¬B)$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\lnot$-introduction, discharging [a].

Thus, steps 3) to 6) are nothing more than an *Indirect Proof* : assume  the negation of the sought conclusion and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. So proving A ⊢ (B→A) would go like: 

1) A      (premise)
2) ¬(B→A) (ass. A)
3) ¬A     (by 1 and 2)
4) ⊥      (by 1 and 4)
5) ¬¬(B→A)(RaA on 1 and 2, discharging [a])
6) (B→A)  (rule for double neg. on 5)

Or would it? (Really just tried some things out).
Thanks.

Comment: @tomtronbone - not exactly ... from $A$ you can infer $(B \to A)$ directly; "intuitively", you need *modus ponens* with the premise $A$ and the tautology : $A \to (B \to A)$.

Comment: You can see in the answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938764/how-is-the-implication-introduction-used-here) the natural deduction proof of $A \vdash (B \to A)$.

Comment: Thanks! But, you don't seem to be using any of the principles - or are you?

Comment: @tomtronbone - in term of *natural deduction* rule, you can derive $B \to A$ from $A$ by $\to$-introduction alone, because you can discharge an assumption ($B$) also when it is not present. The idea is simply : $A \vdash A$ is valid and we can add "unnecessary" assunptions; thus : $A,B \vdash A$ is also valid (with $B$ whatever). Then apply $\to$-intro to get : $A \vdash (B \to A)$.